# Working with permissions httpd server with XAMP , Why can't open logs?

Tags: apache-2.4, mac-osx, file-permissions

I have a couple questions about the permission for Apache httpd server when working on MAC , need your help please ! 
I am using XAMP and when i need to start the server i got log error : 
httpd: could not open error log file

```
/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/logs/error-logs.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Now when i changing the permissions like this : `sudo chmod o+w logs`
I got this output :

`drwxr-xrwx 5 someone admin 170 Nov 27 11:03 logs` and after starting the apache server it can't start .

or

`sudo chmod g+w logs` i got this output:

```
drwxrwxrwx   5 someone  admin  170 Nov 27 11:03 logs
```

Can anybody explain me what permissions do i need to specify for mine apache main httpd.conf `User daemon` `Group daemon` in order to allow apache write to the logs folder ? I am new to the topic so please be patience !!

Answer (score 0):

Unix permissions are not just the target file, but also the path.

To reach and read a specific file you must have at least search permissions in the directory path until you reach where the file is.

Use a command like:
namei -mol "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/sites/beinstyle/logs/error-logs"

If they are correct, it can be that:
1º Directory does not exist.
2º SELinux or similar getting in the way.